# Am I passing array ownership back to caller from my library function?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory, ownership

I came to C from Python. Python has a delightfully simplistic white glove approach to manipulating strings. The more I use arrays in C, the more I think how convenient it would be to have certain features. Rather than writing loops to do this every time I need to do a particular operation, I have decided to create a library to do this.

So, let's say I have a library and the call looks something like this:

`char* new_array = meatSlicer(old_array, element_start);`

I'm passing the pointer to the array I want changed, expecting a pointer return, and indicating what element to slice at.

If `meatSlicer` (yes, I'm a sucker for bad naming) returns a pointer to an array that is made locally within the slicer, the pointer will be a bad pointer. So, within `meatSlicer()` I have this:

```
    ... manipulation before the below ...

    char *heap_the_Array;     /* put it on the heap to pass it back to caller */
    heap_the_Array = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));

    int i;                
    for (i = 0; i <= (size + 1); i++){           /* make it so... again */

            heap_the_Array[i] = newArray[i];     /* newArray is the local */

    }

    return heap_the_Array;                       /* return pointer */
```

**My question is,** am I properly returning ownership to the caller function so that it can `free()` the new array? Is passing a pointer to an array on the heap sufficient for that?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you have to make sure that the caller `free()`s the pointer later on.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, copying local variables into `malloc`-ed regions of memory works well. You can replace the loop with a call of [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) to reduce the code size. Write

```
memcpy(heap_the_Array, newArray, size+1);
```

instead of

```
int i;                
for (i = 0; i <= (size + 1); i++){           /* make it so... again */
        heap_the_Array[i] = newArray[i];     /* newArray is the local */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the simplified command--that's a neat feature. Quick additional question: in my library, do I define the function as `char meatSlicer(...` or do I have to do: `char* meatSlicer(...` ? Not sure if I have to compensate in the declaration when returning a pointer...

Comment: @d0rmLife `char* meatSlicer(..)` is the correct way as you return a pointer to a `char`, not just a `char`.

Comment: @d0rmLife Since the type of `heap_the_Array`, the value that you are returning, is `char*`, your function should be defined as `char *meatSlicer(...`.

Comment: dablinken & @KingsIndian Wait... so does the positioning of the asterisk matter? `char* meatSlicer(...)` verse `char *meatSlicer(...)`?

Comment: @d0rmLife Positioning of the asterisk doesn't matter. Both are same, it's just a matter of style.

Comment: @d0rmLife You can put the asterisk with the space on either side, or even with no space at all. In general, C compiler ignores all whitespace (unlike Python that pays attention to the leading whitespace). Placement of asterisks is a matter of preference. It does not matter with functions, but with variables I always place the asterisk with the variable name, because you can declare several vars of different type in a single declaration, e.g. `int *p, x;` There, `p` is a pointer and `x` is not. If I put the asterisk with an `int`, the code would look misleading (but it would remain the same).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are properly transferring ownership to the caller function. This approach to ownership is not frequently used by C programmers, but it happens sometimes (`strdup` and GNUish `asprintf` are widely-known examples).

You can also work with a heap-allocated array from the very start, eliminating the need for copying.

As of copying itself, by the way, there is a bug in your code: the body of `for (i = 0; i <= (size + 1); i++)` is invoked `size+2` times. Using `memcpy` with the size argument, as hinted by another answer, is indeed less error-prone than doing it yourself.

And the last thing: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 in ANSI C, please don't multiply by it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your meatSlicer is done with heap_the_Array, it belongs now to the caller. So the caller is the only one now who can (and has to) delete that array, unless he passes ownership to somebody else. This ownership idea is something which has to be defined somehow by you, and you have to be consistent with it in order to avoid trouble and avoid beeing sliced by the memory-leak-monster.

Answer (score 1):

It has been clearly explained how the ownership is transferred. However, I would like to propose a "more traditional" approach. Your code looks very much like something I would happily do in Python - but C is not Python (and Python is not C!), part of learning a new language is learning "how things are done in that language". There is a tendency for programmers that are just learning C to jump at calling malloc here there and everywhere. Try to NOT do that.

Instead of letting the function allocate an array, pass in an array in your calling code, that has space for the things you want to copy. Then return how many lements you actually got, for example something like this:

```
 TYPE new_array[some_size];
 int max_size = sizeof(new_array) / sizeof(new_array[0]);
 int actual_size;

 actual_size = meatSlicer(old_array, new_array, element_start, max_size);
```

If you want to use malloc to create new_array, then you can of course do so:

```
 TYPE new_array = malloc(some_size * sizeof(TYPE));
 int max_size = some_size;
 int actual_size;

 if (new_array == NULL) panic();    // Do something useful here. 

 actual_size = meatSlicer(old_array, new_array, element_start, max_size);

 ... 

 free(new_array);
```

I much prefer to use arrays of fixed size, as there is less overhead, and less need to "remember to free later" - the latter is a common problem in code, especially when the code gets a bit more complicated and there are several call levels involved - and if you allocate several items in one function, you need to remember to clean up the first ones if a later allocation fails, for example. Makes life complicated...

Comment: My array will be fixed sized, it will merely be contained in the heap. Isn't it a concern to `free()` if I plan to run my program continuously? Otherwise the heap variables will be automatically deallocated when the currently owning program exits/returns a value. It seems this would **probably** be a bad habit to develop. BUT, I dislike taking the time to declare and calculate the size of the new string in the caller. The point of developing this library would be to avoid those sorts of calculations. I guess that is the tradeoff--between extra lines in the caller function and freeing memory.

Comment: Anyways, you raise an interesting point about embracing the idioms of each language... I will definitely think about that. I feel I am gradually starting to do that with C... gradually... Hah, I find it interesting that you think that my code looks Pythonic!!!

Comment: Yes, of course, heap allocations are eventually freed [unlike OS heap - I do a fair bit of OS programming, so I'm 'extra nervous' about allocations]. But also, if you want your program to run for hours or days, it's definitely useful to not "leak" memory. Python has garbage collection, so as long as you don't let your arrays grow infinitely or something like that, you are OK. But in C, everything allocated SHOULD be freed at some point during program's execution. At least in theory.

Comment: Definitely a good habit that I plan to embrace. My main complaint with this style is, as I mentioned, doing the calculation within the caller function when I desire to merely call a function to simplify matters. I appreciate being reminded about deallocation, though, considering Python's garbage collection.

Comment: Well, assuming you can determine the MAX size, there's little reason to "skimp" a few (hundred) bytes, unless you are going to have hundreds of the things. There is a fair bit of overhead in allocating [as in, 16-32 bytes of 'header' and then rounding to 8, 16 or 32 bytes are common scenarios], so unless you are saving quite a lot and have many, it's not really worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only stack allocated variables are automatically "freed" when a function returns, and you have correctly allocated an array on the heap, and correctly returned a pointer to it.

Specifically, the pointer variable `heap_the_Array` is allocated on the stack, and a copy of that value will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* return a pointer to heap allocated object, it does not mean you can forget NULL terminating the character array :).

It will work, just don't forget to add the trailing '\0' to the mix and don't forget to `free()` the char array once done with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your arrays are strings, you can replace your buggy code with a single line.

```
return strdup(newArray);
```

Comment: I am under the impression there are *only* arrays in C? Thanks for the alternative call, though! I guess I can either allocate to a heap array right away or copy the `old_array` into a local and use `strdup();`